# SQL Server: How to pass input variable of variable length? The length may go up to any limit?

Tags: sql-server

I have comma separated numbers which we need to pass as input to a stored procedure.

The input parameter looks like:

```
@CustStockLogIdList varchar(1000)
```

I am sending input to this parameter like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` and so on. The list could be any length.

I know in this case if it exceeds 1000 characters, it would cut down the passed value to 1000 chars and do rest of processing.

But I am not sure of the length.

As I read limit of varchar is 8000, `@CustStockLogIdList varchar(MAX)` or `@CustStockLogIdList varchar(8000)` would also allow length to be 8000 characters but I want more than that. I am not sure about maximum length I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `VARCHAR(MAX)` which allows to send upto *2GB* of data.

But I will suggest you to use Table valued parameter as procedure input parameter instead of comma separated list as input

```
Create type udt_CustStockLogIdList as table
(
id int
)
```

You need to alter the procedure to accept this `udt_CustStockLogIdList` as parameter.

```
Alter procedure prc_proc_name(@CustStockLogIdList_TT udt_CustStockLogIdList READONLY)
As 
Begin
..
End
```

To call the procedure

```
Declare @CustStockLogIdList_TT udt_CustStockLogIdList

Insert into @CustStockLogIdList_TT
values (1),(2),(3),..

Exec prc_proc_name CustStockLogIdList_TT
```